# YII log separate file name for every class

Tags: php, yii

I want to be able to have for every class its own .log file. 
I don't want to do this manually in the config/main.php file but to somehow 
send it to the log function with another parameter, is that possible (perhaps inherit it somehow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but you will need to write some code. Specifically, you will have to:

#### Create your own implementation of `CLogRoute`

The standard [`CFileLogRoute`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileLogRoute) writes log messages to a single file. It shouldn't be difficult to adapt the code and write your own e.g. `OneFilePerClassLogRoute` that does what you need. For example, the implementation of the [`processLogs`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileLogRoute#processLogs-detail) method starts with

```
protected function processLogs($logs)
{
    $logFile=$this->getLogPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->getLogFile();
    // ...
{
```

The parameter `$logs` is an array; each item is an array that contains four pieces of information (you can see what they are if you look at [`formatLogMessage`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLogRoute#formatLogMessage-detail)). One of these is the "category" of each message. You can use class names for categories and make `processLogs` write each message to a separate file based on its category (i.e. which class it is related to).

#### Pass the necessary information to the logger

Of course to do that, you need to pass the current class name as the category for each log message. Luckily, this is very easy using the [`__CLASS__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant:

```
Yii::log($message, $level, __CLASS__);
```

#### Configure Yii to use your log route

Finally, don't forget to configure Yii with your custom log route as shown in the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#message-routing). Depending on how you write your log route class, it might look something like this:

```
'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'MyCustomLogRoute',
            'logPath'=>'where_your_logs_will_be_saved',
            //...other options for your custom route here...
        ),
        // ...other routes here...
    ),
),
```

Comment: where should the MyCustomLogRoute be located ?

Comment: @Asaf: That's your decision, `/protected/components/` might be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is to extend CLogFilter to add in additional information about the current class/file name into the log.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#logging-context-information